# Trying to append a new node to an existing node doesn't work with custom schema

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui, kendo-treeview

When working with Kendo UI Web v2012.3.1114 the issue that I have is I am trying to do a simple append to a TreeView with a node that I retrieve via an AJAX call to the server fails with the error below.

The node is the EXACT same format as the data returned from the normal read function.
I have successfully used `data("kendoTreeView").insertBefore(...)` for the same tree and call, but when I try to use `data("kendoTreeView").append(...)` it fails.

Error message:

> Uncaught TypeError: Property 'data' of object # is not a
>   function kendo.web.min.js:25

Since I have to be able to create new child nodes for a node that was previously a leaf, I cannot use any other API to do this.

I've made a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/XJbvd/) showing the definition of the tree and what I want to be able to do. I tried referencing the working sample on the Kendo site but it seems that as soon as I use a custom schema, things go south.

Here is the code from jsFiddle that I'm using:

```
function populateHierarchyTree(quotaSetID, columnID, treeDiv) {

    var transport = {
        read: {
            url: '/Quota/QuotaHierarchy/GetQuotaHierarchyChildrenFromParent',
            dataType: 'json',
            data: { columnDefinitionID: columnID, quotaSetID: quotaSetID, batchSize:10 },
            type: 'POST'
        }
    };

    var schema = {
        model: {
            id: 'id',
            hasChildren: 'hasChildren'
        }
    };

    var dataSource = new kendo.data.HierarchicalDataSource({
        transport: transport,
        schema: schema
    });

    treeDiv.kendoTreeView({
        loadOnDemand: true,
        dataSource: dataSource,
        dataTextField: "text",
    });
}

// This function is called with a single node which contains the exact same structure returned from GetQuotaHierarchyChildrenFromParent used by the read. ParentElement could be anything.
function AddNode(node,parentElement,treeView){
    treeView.append(node,parentElement);
}
```

Comment: did you realize that you typed `Append` and not `append`?

Comment: That was a mistake. I meant append.

Answer (score 2):

How do you choose `parentElement`? Are you sure that it is a `kendoTreeView` node?

Try this:

```
treeView.append(node, parentElement.closest(".k-item"));
```

By adding `.closest(".k-item");` what I try is finding the closest `node` ancestor of your `parentNode`.

Comment: I use .parents(".k-item").eq(0) on my parent_elem because I am tracking an internal element so it should work just the same. As I said before, if I call insertBefore, it inserts the node just before the parent element so I believe the parent is being found properly.

Comment: Actually `insertBefore` is not as picky as `append` and if you try `insertBefore` with an invalid selector, it appends the new node at root level.

Comment: Would you mind updating the fiddle and showing exactly how you select the node where you are going to append? I mean, `AddNode` invocation with each parameter and how you select each parameter. In the meantime I'm going to change your fiddle showing how it works for me.

Comment: I've updated the jsfiddle to http://jsfiddle.net/XJbvd/5/ and placed EXACTLY how i use append. Currently, the only case that does NOT work is when I use append. I've used chrome to pause right before appending, and the node object is proper and so is the targeted parent element selector.

Comment: I've also noted that if I have expanded the node (IE, it has children visible) then it works fine. Perhaps something is wrong with how i select a parent. How should i do it if the node doesn't have any children yet? Just selecting the k-item doesn't seem to work.

Comment: What I've been able to see is that when you append content to a `treeView` and you have `loadOnDemand: true` it `expands` the `node` causing also the next level to be loaded.

Comment: @PaulSachs, please check [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/OnaBai/dyNje/). It is basically your yesterday code. Instead of loading the data from the server it uses a local array but anyway I think it is pretty similar to your code. If you select a node (click) and then press _append_ `button`, it uses your `AddNode` function for adding new content.

Comment: This sample works fine, as does the provided documentation sample, it just doesn't work in my complicated use case, I see an error in the kendo js. The only difference I can see is some other stuff i didn't include in the jsfiddle because i didn't think it would make a difference. I use the checkboxes and template options to provide some template things. I'll include that in a new [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/XJbvd/8/). Maybe that will make a difference.

Comment: You might also try to start removing your _complicated use case_ little by little converging to the _nominal case_ and see when it starts working. Then investigate just that _little change_.

Comment: So I've narrowed down what seems to be the cause. My server sends back the list of children as items: [] being an empty list. If i have that and try to add children, it blows up. If items: null, it works fine. You can simulate it on the same by initializing items as [] on any node.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/21478/discussion-between-onabai-and-paul-sachs)